# incompatible types : "int[] variable cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>"

Tags: java, arraylist

Goal:Sink all the computers Dot Coms in the 5 Guesses,you are given rating how well you perform ie numOfGuesses

setup: when program is launched,the computer places three dotcoms on virtual 7X1 grid.When that's complete,The game asks for your first guess.

How it works : This whole thing works on cmd-line,The computer will ask you to enter a guess(a cell),That you'll type at the cmd-line as "0","2",etc.In response to your guess,you'll see a result at the cmd-line,either "Hit","Miss"or "kill",when you get kill the game ends  printing your num of guesses taken to kill ie value of variable numOfGuesses

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class DotCom
{

    private ArrayList<String> locationCells;    // to hold the location cells

    public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> loc) //setter method that takes an int array(which has three cell locations as ints(2,3,4,etc))
{

        locationCells = loc;

}

    public String checkYourself(String userInput)   //method that takes a String for the user's Input("1","3",etc).checks it and returns a result representing a "hit","miss" or "kill".
{

        String result = "miss"; //when you miss hit the randomNum value generated

        int index = locationCells.indexOf(userInput);   //checks the index of the userInput(user's Input),from the locationCells and Stores the value in index int variable

        if(index >= 0)  
{

            locationCells.remove(index);    //removes the index position(user's guess)from the array,so that the same value don't get accepted again 

        if(locationCells.isEmpty()) //if locationCells array goes empty
{

            result = "kill"; // when you hit all the three randomNum values

}
        else
{

            result = "hit"; //when you  hit the randomNum value

}
}
            System.out.println(result); //print result
            return result;

}
}
class DotComTestDrive
{

    public static void main(String []args)
{

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int numOfGuesses = 0;   //for storing user guesses

            DotCom dot = new DotCom();  //dot com instance variable

            int randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*5); //to get a random value as an int variable and store in randomNum variable

            int[] location = {randomNum,randomNum+1,randomNum+2}; //

            dot.setLocationCells(location);

            boolean isAlive = true;

    while(isAlive == true  && numOfGuesses < 6) 
{

            System.out.println("Enter Your Guess : ");

            String userInput = user_input.next();   //take user input(user's guess)

            String result = dot.checkYourself(userInput);

            numOfGuesses++;

    if(result.equals("kill"))
{

            isAlive = false;

            System.out.println("You Took " + numOfGuesses + " guesses");

}
}
}
}
```

"int[] variable cannot be converted to ArrayList" getting the above error for the following line "dot.setLocationCells(location);"

Comment: Right, well the error message seems reasonably clear - what did you expect to happen? Do you understand that `int[]` and `ArrayList<String>` are entirely different types?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: What's with the mad indentation?

Comment: @khelwood I've seen you ask about the "mad intention" a couple of times. Whilst I must admit I find it faintly amusing, I don't think this really counts as ["being nice"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), which says "Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").". "Mad" feels like it belongs in that list to me. Maybe just consider dropping it?

Comment: We are not much interested in your game here. If you have a programming related question, then ask it, and provide the relevant code (and not the complete "game").

Comment: @AndyTurner I think it is worth pointing out when questions have mad indentation so that people know they have got something wrong. Also I am often genuinely puzzled by some people's indentation choices, and would be happy for someone to answer the comment with an explanation. But I'm happy to try and come up with a different stock comment in the interests of niceness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setLocationCells function accepts an `ArrayList<String>`, but you give it an `int[]`. Your comment says that the function accepts an `int[]`, so you should probably change the parameter to be an `int[]`. You'll also need to make `locationCells` an `int[]`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert your `int[]` into a `ArrayList<String>` because your method parameter asks for an `ArrayList<String>`, not an `int[]`. Do this by:

```
private List<String> convertIntArr(int[] input) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>(input.length);
    for (int x : input) {
        output.add(String.valueOf(x));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Tested with input of `int[]` as `{ 1, 2, 3 }`, output of `List<String>` as `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in comments, you're trying to provide an int array to a function that takes an ArrayList of String as the argument.

I don't know which one is the correct type, but either way you need to provide the correct type. If the function should indeed take an `ArrayList<String>` (which seems probable judging from the rest of the code), you should replace the line

```
int[] location = {randomNum,randomNum+1,randomNum+2};
```

with

```
ArrayList<String> location = new ArrayList<String>();
location.add( String.valueOf(randomNum) );
location.add( String.valueOf(randomNum+1) );
location.add( String.valueOf(randomNum+2) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your setLocationCells(ArrayList loc) is taking ArrayList as parameter and you are trying to send int[] in it. Hence the error

Comment: Please suggest a solution. You're just restating the error in the question.